# Quels sont les différents régimes de construction du verbe par rapport à la notion de complément ?

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour à tous,
J'essaye d'apprendre la grammaire française à l'institut français en Iran, mais j'ai un peu de mal avec ces notions.
Dans un des exercices, une des questions est "Quels sont les différents régimes de construction du verbe par rapport à la notion de complément ?"
Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait répondre à cette question ?
Cordialement

Comment: Voir ici : http://www.cosmovisions.com/complement.htm

Comment: J'imagine que c'est un cours déjà plutôt avancé? N'étant pas moi-même un professionnel de la langue j'aurais beaucoup de mal à répondre à cette question. J'avoue avoir même du mal à la comprendre.

Answer (score 1):

Le terme de régime n'est plus utilisé dans l'enseignement scolaire du français, que ce soit le français pour les natifs ou le français langue étrangère (FLE).
Les anciens grammairiens parlaient de *régime*, entendant par ce terme « la dépendance d'un nom ou d'un pronom par rapport à un autre mot de la même phrase ». ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/r%C3%A9gime), **Régime**, 8-*Terme de grammaire*.)

Il y a deux régimes qui régissent la construction du verbe par rapport à la notion de  complément :

1. Le **régime direct** quand l'action du verbe tombe directement sur le mot.

- Ex. 1 : je mange une pomme
  *pomme* est le régime direct.

2. Le **régime indirect** quand l'action du verbe ne tombe pas  directement sur le mot.

- Ex. 2 :  je parle à mon frère.
  *mon frère* est le régime indirect.

De nos jours on dit plus volontiers que dans l'exemple 1 *pomme* est complément d'objet direct et dans l'exemple 2 que *mon frère* est complément d'objet indirect.

Answer (score 0):

D'après de nombreuses sources il n'y a pas de différence entre « régime » et « complément ». De nos jours on utilise cependant presque pas « régime » et « complément » est le mot que l'on trouve dans les grammaires ([Wiktionnaire, n° 9](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9gime)).

On trouve cependant [ici](https://hongroisavecandras.blog4ever.com/le-regime-des-verbes-des-expressions-verbales-et-des-adjectifs) une définition du mot qui ne correspond pas à la définition souvent reconnue (c'est à dire « complément ») et qui semble bien plus judicieuse : ne pas avoir de complément est un régime selon cette définition.

> Les verbes, les expressions verbales et les adjectifs peuvent ou non avoir un complément ou des compléments de certains types, ce qui constitue leur régime.

En d'autres mots, cette définition implicite nous dit que le régime d'un verbe c'est le type de complémentation utilisé, ou encore, sa forme. Néanmoins, je ne trouve pas d'autre trace de ce point de vue, qui est à mon avis le seul qui soit raisonnable.

Cela semble être  confirmé quand même par ce que l'on trouve dans l'[encyclopédie de Diderot](http://xn--encyclopdie-ibb.eu/index.php/602997758-REGIME).

> RÉGIME S. m. terme de Grammaire ; ce mot vient du latin regimen, gouvernement : il est employé en Grammaire dans un sens figuré, dont on peut voir le fondement à l'article GOUVERNER. Il s'agit ici d'en déterminer le sens propre par rapport au langage grammatical. Quoiqu'on ait insinué, à l'article que l'on vient de citer, qu'il fallait donner le nom de complément à ce que l'on appelle régime, il ne faut pourtant pas confondre ces deux termes comme synonymes : je vais déterminer la notion précise de l'un et de l'autre en deux articles séparés ; et par-là je suppléerai l'article COMPLEMENT, que M. du Marsais a omis en son lieu, quoiqu'il fasse fréquemment usage de ce terme.

> Il suit de-là qu'à prendre le mot régime dans le sens généralement adopté, il n'aurait jamais dû être employé, par rapport aux noms et aux pronoms, dans les grammaires particulières des langues analogues qui ne déclinent point, comme le français, l'italien, l'espagnol, etc. car le régime est dans ce sens la forme particulière que doit prendre un complement grammatical d'un mot en conséquence du rapport particulier sous lequel il est alors envisagé : or dans les langues qui ne déclinent point, les mots paraissent constamment sous la même forme, et conséquemment il n'y a point proprement de régime.

[GOUVERNER, encycl. Diderot](http://xn--encyclopdie-ibb.eu/index.php/logique/929124137-grammaire/907387722-GOUVERNER) On pouvait cependant éviter l'emploi abusif du mot dont il est ici question, ainsi que des mots régir et régime, destinés au même usage. Il était plus simple de donner le nom de complément à ce que l'on appelle régime, parce qu'il sert en effet à rendre complet le sens qu'on se propose d'exprimer ; et alors on aurait dit tout simplement : le complément de telles prépositions doit être à tel cas ; le complément objectif du verbe actif doit être à l'accusatif, etc. M. Dumarsais a fait usage de ce mot en bien des occurrences, sans en faire en son lieu un article exprès : nous développerons nos vues sur cet objet au mot REGIME, en y exposant les principes de Grammaire qui peuvent y avoir rapport. On y verra que l'on peut quelquefois à peu de frais répandre la lumière sur les éléments des Sciences et des Arts. (E. R. M.)

Il me semble donc les différents régimes de construction du verbe en ce qui concerne la notion de complément sont les différents possibilités d'ajout d'un complément: de façon transitive, ou intransitive, ou transitive et intransitive,  etc. Donc, la définition de « régime » n'est pas la définition courante dans cette phrase.

- La région est aride. (*régime attributif*)